# Gradle :Hostname may not contain blanks

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

While importing exisiting gradle project in eclipse , I am getting an error message which says

> "IllegalArgumentException:Host name may not contain blanks".

I verified my `gradle-wrapper.properties` and found that proxyHost, port, username and password are correct.What might be causing this error in this case?

I am using springboot, gradlewrapper and gradle-4.8.1.zip already exists in the project.

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you checked headers values ?

Comment: If you use proxy, then make sure you do not have spaces after proxy server in your: gradle.properties: systemProp.http.proxyHost=example.net "space"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have spaces in the values(in the beginning or end) of properties systemProp.https.proxyHost and systemProp.http.proxyHost